# How do I get these strange characters when I try to "echo" the html string?

Tags: php, html, echo, character

I am sending the echo to mail function via PHP from variable that includes HTML code. The strange thing is, that this

```
<����}im�
```

shows up AFTER the string.. but I do not manipulate with it anymore. The charset of mail function (the attachment) is same as charset of HTML code.

Comment: I think we need more details. Can you find which byte sequences generate the invalid characters? (view with a hex editor?)

Comment: I believe you may find good informations in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411 question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding problem, maybe it tries to display binary code?

You should use htmlentities if ou want to display HTML

> // Outputs: A 'quote' is
>
> <b>bold</b> echo
>
> htmlentities($str);

Comment: I am not sure I understand this but I'll check on google :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are probably "junk" data in your string.  Depending on where the string is coming from these characters could be: extra TCP data in the socket after the HTML page, or extra data in the file after the HTML page, or someone else actually put these characters in their HTML page (perhaps their file was accidentally corrupted, or for some other reason).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [htmlMimeMail](http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html) class for handling the email. So you can avoid the nasty email internals.

Comment: How the hell do I download it??? I can't download PHP files from web! http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/html.mime.mail/htmlMimeMail-2.5.2/

Comment: You can copy-paste the contents of the phps files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem I have.. I use the code from Internet source, the $body is generated invoice and this send the email.. Those characters are at the end of HTML source file but I don't understand why the hell they are there :(

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Invoice';
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers = "From: mymail@mymail.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$body=rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($body))); 
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text Emailu.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"; name="faktura.html" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo htmlentities($body); ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```