# file_get_contents - special characters in URL

Tags: php

I am trying to get images from a remote server using `file_get_contents`. A URL to an image may contain spaces and/or special characters like ý, á, í, etc and when it does the operation fails with a HTTP code 400 - Bad Request. If I try to encode the url (or segments of that URL), using `urlencode` or `rawurlencode`, I get a 404.

When the image URL does not contain spaces nor special chars it is downloaded without problems.

I have a hunch that this has got something to do with encoding but I just can't figure it out.
Is there an encoding option I'm missing? Is there a header that must be set for the request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: alickus: That's not actually a duplicate, the question you linked is about UTF-8 in the response content, not the URL.

Comment: Open up that image in your browser. See how browser encodes URL. Then see the output of `echo urlencode($url);` and find differences

Comment: How about cleaning file names of special characters and then doing the same with the user input?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with file_get_contents is the UTF-8 encoding (didn't implemented yet in PHP)
If you want download file with this function, you have to do something like that on your URL:

`$url_utf8 = rawurlencode(utf8_encode($url));`

And after:

`$content = file_get_contents($url_utf8);`

Comment: This can lead to unpredicted results unless the PHP file is saved as `ISO-8859-1`.