# PHP file_get_contents specific encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, file-get-contents

i have one special issue with file_get_contents in PHP, here is code:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.bratm.sk/trochu-harlem-inspiracie-zaslite-nam-svoj-super-harlem-shake-ak-bude-husty-zverejnime-ho");
```

it gives me something like this

```
í}KsŰĆŇčÚŽň!Ç& zRŚ|iI[#)öIkI ĆĺăĹŮÝĹÍý_ŐŃâ[EVßîV%Ů˙ëvĎ ř)śG#óčééééÇĚ çáÜöÁÖÉ;¤áˇ,rřĂăçť[DQ5íeaKÓśOśÉ?ě='šL¸ÔöLßä6ľ4mg_!JĂ÷˘Śu:L§án];9ŇÎV+Ş¨1|C
```

in some pages from this page i can get proper encoding and content with iconv, but here im helpless, how can i fix that? thx

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2236698/925897) solves the issue pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cURL. This function is an alternative to file_get_contents.

```
function url_get_contents($Url) {
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}
$data = url_get_contents("http://www.bratm.sk/trochu-harlem-inspiracie-zaslite-nam-svoj-super-harlem-shake-ak-bude-husty-zverejnime-ho/");
print_r($data);
```

Comment: with this i get empty string

Comment: can you try it again please?

`function url_get_contents ($Url) {
   if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
       die('CURL is not installed!');
   }
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $output;
};

$html = url_get_contents("http://www.bratm.sk/trochu-harlem-inspiracie-zaslite-nam-svoj-super-harlem-shake-ak-bude-husty-zverejnime-ho/");
echo $html;exit;`

Comment: I edited my post and there is working code. What I noticed in your comment that you don't need ";" after function..

Comment: its totaly weird but now this page works... but another `"http://www.bratm.sk/viagra-jedine-vysvetlenie-ako-tam-ta-zena-drzi-d-d/"` still not, can you try this one too?

Comment: if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    return 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: no error there... can you try this please?

`function url_get_contents($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        return 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$data = url_get_contents("http://www.bratm.sk/viagra-jedine-vysvetlenie-ako-tam-ta-zena-drzi-d-d/");
echo($data);`

Comment: im really dont understand this, but now this url works (im didnt change anything), but next page `"http://www.bratm.sk/ako-sa-robi-iglu/"` not...

Comment: ok, i have it finally! problem was that pages are GZIPed, to solutuion is to add curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');  to curl options, thx for help!

Answer (score 2):

That page is in UTF-8. You need to set the header to match:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: thx, but its not help... and anyway, i dont need to display it, i need to crawl in this code

Comment: What exactly are you doing with it? Storing it the DB? Looking for something within it? Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: I already tried solutions in that topic, and actualy it works, but not in all pages... for example try that exact page which is in example

and yes, i need to save some content to DB - Open Graph data

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$filename = "http://www.bratm.sk/trochu-harlem-inspiracie-zaslite-nam-svoj-super-harlem-    shake-ak-bude-husty-zverejnime-ho";
echo file_get_contents($filename, false, $context);
```