# file_get_contents return json with extra unexpected characters

Tags: php, json

I just noticed an odd result with my code:

```
$data = @file_get_contents($url);  //gets json format from API
return $data;
```

It returns a random character in front of the first `{` and after the last `}`.
Because of this, I cant use `json_decode()` because the json is now invalid because of the extra characters.

I have checked the actual api url and it doesn't have those random characters.
Why could this be happening?

Note: Sometimes it even returns a black diamond with a white question mark.

---

I'm reading API's from Steam Community.

---

I improvised with a temporary fix while im trying to find the code causing the problem.

```
$data = substr($data, 1, -1);
```

Comment: Which is the API url?

Comment: @madziikoy Got a 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: Have you checked your own files for UTF-8 BOM's?

Comment: @Wrikken No, I guess I don't even know what that is.

Comment: @WayneWhitty sorry. That was wrong. changed it now.

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the urls indeed, content-length is also OK. And it works here... must be something in your files/code I'd say..

Comment: @Wrikken I'm using a library called steam-condenser. I think there is a bug in his codes. I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a character encoding issue.

The response header of the api-request:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Please have a look at an equivalent issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case.