# php - read content web page for especial address

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, page-curl, file-put-contents

I want get content of this [Web Page](http://www.chinanews.com/rss/scroll-news.xml)
using php functions (e.g `file_put_contents`, `curl_init` etc.) but I get `�������` as response.

### Why does that happen?

I solved my problem. after get content web page,I using mb_convert_encoding($body_webpage,"UTF-8","GBK") and now this is saveable in mysql whith chinese characters.

Comment: It's probably using unicode.

Comment: Which one are you using file_* or curl_*?  Show the code.

Comment: check this question, it may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: Still alive ?! Your problem is related with bad character encoding, check my answer below.

Comment: As the XML file header declares, the file is encoded as GB2312. You'll need to convert that as appropriate to your desired encoding. Likely you should leave this up to a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you need to do in order to get the Chinese page displayed correctly.

Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser

```
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

Tell the bowser that we'll be using UTF-8 charset

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
```

---

---

I've successfully loaded the page, with the correct character encoding, by using the code below:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.chinanews.com/rss/scroll-news.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$pagebody=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
echo $pagebody;
?>
```

---

Learn more about utf-8 character encoding at

https://phpbestpractices.org/#utf-8

Comment: thank's Pedro Lobito. I want store $pagebody in mysql table with utf8_general_ci collection. But store filed is empty after execute insert query. I want store chinese character.

Comment: @hediehloo add MySQL as a tag, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and tell us whether you are using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Those two `mb` functions aren't really doing anything here. `mb_internal_encoding` just sets an internal value that other functions use, it doesn't itself do anything of importance here. `mb_http_output` is an output filter which automatically converts any output from the *internal encoding* to the given output encoding. Since both are UTF-8 nothing will happen.