# Readind utf8 encoded text file

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a script that reads data from text file encoded in utf8. It reads characters one by one with `fgetc()`. When it reads simple ascii charactes it's fine but when it comes to  š, č, ž... It doesn't work correctly. The simplified code looks like this:

```
$file = fopen($path);
$char = fgetc($file);
while( $char !== false) {
    $char = fgetc($file);
    fwrite(STDOUT, $char);
}
```

I tried to use

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

at the beginning of the script, but it still doesn't work. I also tried to use `utf8_encode($char)` or `utf8_decode($char)`, it didn't help. Is there any simple solution how to read utf8 characters and write them to output?

UPDATE:

The problem is that special characters are saved in two indexes, so when I call one fgetc I don't get the whole character. My solution for now is that when I get a character with ordinal number above 127 I call fgetc again and make a string from those two values from fgetc, then I can correctly fwrite loaded special character. Maybe it's not the best solution but I couldn't figure out anything better.

Comment: What doesn't work correctly?

Comment: The problem is that special characters are saved in two indexes, so when I call one `fgetc` I don't get the whole character. My solution for now is that when I get a character with ordinal number above 127 I call `fgetc` again and make a string from those two values from `fgetc`, then I can correctly `fwrite` loaded special character. Maybe it's not the best solution but I couldn't figure out anything better.

Comment: please update your question with that information. I have an idea that may help you

Comment: Is it possible to read the whole file? If so, the mb_* functions will allow you to get single chars at a time from a string. I'm not sure if PHP has a "read one multibyte char from file" method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already set $char before the loop?

```
while( $char !== false)
```

Else you will never start the while loop which could be the problem as you would never call `$char = fgetc($file);`

Comment: I forgot to add it to the example, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Okay in this case why don't you read in the whole File as a String with file_get_contents and try the approach that was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: I was looking for a solution where my script could work the way it works now - reading characters one by one, I didn't want to load the whole file.