# How to make a custom function available to all Codeception tests

Tags: codeception

I'm working on some Codeception acceptance tests, and one thing that I want to check is whether or not my application's e-mails are being sent with the correct text.

In order to do that, I'm comparing the actually *sent* text with a txt dump of what the text should actually be. I'm loading the txt dump with `file_get_contents`. Unfortunately the text contains a copyright symbol (©) which file_get_contents loads as ┬⌐ due to encoding issues. That means I'll need to take a few extra steps any time I load those files with UTF-8 characters.

A solution that I liked was @Gordon's suggestion of a [file_get_contents_utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236698/1809762) function.

What's the best way to make that function available to all of my tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a helper method.

1. Create new helper: `codecept generate:helper Utf8`
2. Add your method to `tests/_support/Helper/Utf8.php`
3. Enable helper in each suite:

   `modules:
     enabled:
       - \Helper\Utf8`

Documentation: http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Helpers