# thank you page after form does not show

Tags: php, email, send

How can I after this mail has been sent through a send_mail.php get the page to go directly to another thank you page called tack.php on the same location in the structure as this mail.inc.php-file?

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");
function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file) {
    $boundary = md5(rand());
    $headers = array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8; boundary=\"{$boundary}\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit", //Nytt 170711
        "From: {$from}"
    );
    $message = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        //'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=iso-8859-1', 170707
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable', 
        '', 
        quoted_printable_encode($body), // Här är nya innehåll kodat som quoted-printable istället. 
        '',                             // Kommer orsaka en extra radbrytning efter meddelandet.
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64", 
        '',
        chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']))),
        "--{$boundary}--",
        '',
    );
    mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't send a `Content-Type` header, instead send a `Redirect` header after the function call.

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean? :)

Comment: remove your first header: "php header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");" you don't need it since you're not supposed to return anything

Answer (score 3):

Add the header at the end of your code:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank_you.php');
```

It will redirect the user to the specified page

EDIT:

Also remove your first header:

```
php header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");
```

you don't need it since you're not supposed to return anything

Comment: Try adding the header after the call of your function "mail_file"

Comment: I think it works! :)
Now there is just one problem. My ÅÄÖ to Gmail on my android phone comes out with a questionmark symbol. Hotmail is ok and both are ok on webmail. Anyone?

Comment: It is Swedish...hehehe. We use them a lot here

Comment: Take a look at  [file_get_contents break UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters)

Comment: Did you find what was the issue, if yes, I'll be happy to know.