# CSV to PHP file - Issue with multi language words

Tags: php, csv

I am reading CSV file to PHP. File is reading properly except one thing. Issue is in reading words which are in non-English language.

Array is returning some symbols instead of other language exact word.

For eg: LBL_Hello   Hello   你好

Above contents are there in  CSV file. I am reading the words into PHP in form of Array using below code:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("test.csv");
    $data = (array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file)));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(($data));
    exit;

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => LBL_Hello
            [1] => Hello
            [2] => ���
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

Here, Chinese word "你好" is showing as "���". This is happened with all other language words also.

Please help me to know what is missing so that I can get the exact other language word while reading CSV into PHP.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried mb_split instead of preg_split?(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php)

Comment: it't not worked- Nigel Ren

Comment: There are some issues with file_get_contents, have a look at things like... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Answer (score -1):

Try sending **charset** headers at the top of file(before any other output)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')
```

Sample Code to get data(contains Non-English characters) from CSV:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$handle = fopen ("test.csv", "r");
$dataArr = [];
echo "<pre>";
while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ",")) {
    array_push($dataArr, $data);
}
print_r($dataArr);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
?>
```

Comment: thank you for response my que. but this is not working - sampth kumar

Comment: and i also use header set