# php file_get_contents() converts html entities like &ouml; to ö

Tags: php, html, entities

I try to display the contents of a php file in a textarea with

```
<textarea ...>
<?php echo file_get_contents("file.php"); ?>
</textarea>
```

but it converts the html entities like `&ouml;` to ö. As it is php code I can not use a conversion like htmlspecialchars because it would brick the <> and quotes etc.

EDIT:

I checked the sourcecode with the browser and there is really an ö.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: How are you looking at the output? Through a browser? That will do the conversion for you. Look at the source code the browser receives.

Comment: Give us an example of the file.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents() Breaks Up UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**htmlspecialchars** will change:

```
< &ouml;
```

to:

```
&lt; &amp;ouml;
```

### **and it's ok.**

It will display in textarea:

```
< &ouml;
```

After you submit form, it will send to server text

```
< &ouml;
```

not:

```
&lt; &amp;ouml;
```

Tested in Chrome with jQuery:

```
$('#layout').html('<form method="POST"><textarea name="x">&lt;&amp;ouml;</textarea><input type="submit" /></form>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some `non-UTF-8` character in your `file.php`.  Try this:

```
     $content = file_get_contents('/tmp/file.php');
     $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true)); 
     print_r($content);
```

You can refer this comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#85008.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea ...>
<?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("file.php")); ?>
</textarea>
```

Example

Convert some characters to HTML entities:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Go to w3schools.com</a>';
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

The HTML output of the code above will be (View Source):

```
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com&quot;&gt;Go to w3schools.com&lt;/a&gt;
```

The browser output of the code above will be:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Go to w3schools.com</a>
```

Comment: As I wrote I can not convert it because the which should be displayed contains html tags whick would be bricked to &lt;  The textarea will be used   to edit the code so I need both the real <> and the &lt;

Comment: <?php 
echo html_entity_decode(file_get_contents("file.php"));
?>