# I keep receiving strange characters when output file's content and title in a place of Polish characters

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I want my program to display a list of files and their content in the browser. The problem is when I use `file_get_contents ($file_name)` I receive a string with diamond question marks `�` in place where Polish characters should be.

```
$content = file_get_contents($file_name);
echo $content;
```

I've tried to use:

```
$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($file_name));
```

But that just replaces question marks with some strange characters like: ``, `ñ`, `³`, `¿`, etc. I've tried to outsmart it by making a switch to replace them with Polish characters individualy, but that failed as the switch wasn't detecting them.

```
function translate($string) {
       $translated = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
         $letter = substr($string, $i, 1);
         switch($letter) {
          case '':
            $letter = 'ś';
            break;
          case 'ñ':
            $letter = 'ń';
            break;
          case '³':
            $letter = 'ł';
            break;
          case '¿':
            $letter = 'ż';
            break;
          case 'æ':
            $letter = "ć";
            break;
          case '¹':
            $letter = 'ą';
            break;
          case 'ê':
             $letter = "ę";
             break;
          case '³':
              $letter = "ć";
              break;`
           }
             $translated = $translated . $letter;
          }
           return $translated;
         }
```

I have to add, that all Polish characters work OK in HTML or nested PHP. Only these I get within file's content are replaced.

Comment: Hello, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents() Breaks Up UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters)