# Laravel - Sever is not reading the files from the path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a problem with my Laravel application. It is deployed on the server and uses `nginx` as the main web server.

I am unable to read two files from the path I set in the deployment server, but on the local environment, it is working fine. These two files are confidential, one is `.crt` file and second is `.pem` file. I placed both of these files in `laravel-app/app/Certificates` directory.

`laravel-app/app/Certificates/test2-2023_cert.pem`

`laravel-app/app/Certificates/curl-bundle.crt`

The file path in `.env` is set like this:

```
PEM=/Certificates/test2-2023_cert.pem
CRT=/Certificates/curl-bundle.crt
```

My `config/services` file:

```
<?php

return [

    'pay' => [
        'pem' => app_path() . env('PEM', ''),
        'crt' => app_path() . env('CRT', '')
    ]

];
```

My `Controller` construct function:

```
public function __construct()
    {
      
        $this->pem = config('services.pay.pem');
        $this->crt = config('services.pay.crt');
    }
```

It is returning the following path on server:

```
/var/www/laravel-app/app/Certificates/test2-2023_cert.pem
/var/www/laravel-app/app/Certificates/curl-bundle.crt
```

but the server is not loading the file and gives me an error response in the API call. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you want just to load the path or read the file ?

Comment: Most likely its an issue with apache/linux and having the word "Certificates" being capital, try renaming it to lower case and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @KGG no issues if you define it correctly. As per the question, it is correct

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have to read the files from the defined path. In my local Laravel app it is working fine but not on the server.

Comment: @KGG I try it but the same issue.

Comment: @VenNilson, you need API to return` app/Certificates/test2-2023_cert.pem` or contents of his file. did you try `File::get(app_path('Certificates/test2-2023_cert.pem'))` in **services.php**

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I called this: `InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file`

Comment: That means that @AbdullaNilam code is working, you just have parsing of data issues, we have no idea what content is in the file or what you will do with it, are you downloading it? rendering it? how is *.pem encoded*? you can try a different approach to download: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters you can also pass a header to handle downloads examples (Content-type / Content-Transfer-Encoding)