# How to read individual national characters from an array

Tags: php

I read a word with national characters from the "txt" file and put it in the table.
I read this word from the table and it is ok, it displays the correct characters.

I need to compare the first letter of a word with the letter tag - if it matches (it is the same), I display the word that starts with that letter.
Unfortunately, if the file being downloaded (the first letter, i.e. [0] ) is a national character, I get �
I know that the problem is in bytes but I can't deal with it. Files saved in UTF=8
Please help.

```
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        if (is_dir($file)){
$taxon = $file;

$file_info_01c = $taxon . '/' . $taxon . '_info_01c.txt';
$file_info_01c_text = file_get_contents($file_info_01c);
$file_info_all[] = [
            'taxon' => $taxon,
            'file_info_01c_text' => $file_info_01c_text
            ];

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

//--- all above works ok

foreach ($file_info_all as $file_info){
    $taxon = $file_info['taxon'];
    $file_info_01c_text = $file_info['file_info_01c_text'];

//--- bottom works ok for latina letters, not for "eĘ, óÓ, ąĄ, śŚ, łŁ, żŻ, źŹ, ćĆ, ńŃ"
    if ($file_info_01c_text[0] === $letter){

echo $file_info_01c_text[0]; }
```

PS. there are subdirectories in the "root" directory. The script reaches into each subdirectory (called "katalog xyz") and reads a word from a file called "katalog_info_01c.txt."
The reading of the word is correct.
The word is entered into the table.
Reading the WHOLE word from the table is correct.
Reading of the first letter is wrong.

->>> The solution and code change

> > $file_info_01c_text_0 = mb_substr($file_info_01c_text,0,1,'UTF-8');

> > if ($file_info_01c_text_0 === $letter){

// thanks for help for all of you :))

Comment: Sorry ->> letter tag ($letter) is for eg. "Ś"

Comment: Can you share more details, like sample input, such that others could try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sample word from "$taxon.'_info_01c.txt" file is "Świnia" (eng. pig) so the first letter is "Ś". The letter tag is "$letter = 'Ś';"

Comment: Have a look at [mb_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr). It can work with UTF-8.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: @KIKO Software - thank You very much, it's working ok. :))

Comment: @Lajos Arpad - thank You, I think it will be helpful for foreign characters in longer text. For now, a solution for just the first character is sufficient. :))