# iconv - Detected an illegal character in input string

Tags: php, iconv

I don't see anything illegal - any suggestions on what might be the problem?

```
    if (strtolower($matches[1]) != 'utf-8') {
        var_dump($matches[1]);
        $xml = iconv($matches[1], 'utf-8', $xml);
        $xml = str_replace('encoding="'.$matches[1].'"', 'encoding="utf-8"', $xml);
    }
```

Below is my debug/error

```
string(12) "windows-1252"
Notice (8): iconv() [http://php.net/function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string [APP/models/sob_form.php, line 16]
```

I've verified that the above code is indeed line 16

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The illegal character is not in `$matches[1]`, but in `$xml`

Try

```
iconv($matches[1], 'utf-8//TRANSLIT', $xml);
```

And showing us the input string would be nice for a better answer.

Comment: I get the same notice even when I put "//TRANSLIT" on both sides

Comment: Use `//IGNORE` instead

Answer (score 55):

If you used the accepted answer, however, you will still receive the PHP Notice if a character in your input string cannot be transliterated:

```
<?php
$cp1252 = '';

for ($i = 128; $i < 256; $i++) {
    $cp1252 .= chr($i);
}

echo iconv("cp1252", "utf-8//TRANSLIT", $cp1252);

PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in CP1252.php on line 8

Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in CP1252.php on line 8
```

So you should use IGNORE, which will ignore what can't be transliterated:

```
echo iconv("cp1252", "utf-8//IGNORE", $cp1252);
```

Comment: I get the same notice even when I put "//IGNORE" on both sides

Comment: What do you mean on both sides?

Comment: And @ErelSegal-Halevi, I would like to see your code.

Comment: @Mantas But Erel was replying to the `//IGNORE` text in my answer, which is why I was confused by your praising of him.

Comment: It was a long time ago, but from what I remember, my code was something like: echo iconv("cp1252//IGNORE", "utf-8//IGNORE", $cp1252);

Comment: That might explain it. You can't add flags to the in_charset of iconv, but you're right; this question is pretty old lol. Good thing I love necroposts.

Comment: In my case, using `//IGNORE` seems to delete the entire string? The hex values of the string: `4f 62 65 72 6b 72 c3 a4 6d 65 72` (= "Oberkrämer"), which becomes empty if I use `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string), 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', ($string));`

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Can you debug/output the result of `mb_detect_encoding($string)`? And you say `//TRANSLIT` is resulting in an empty string, or `//IGNORE`? You also don't need to put the second instance of `$string` in parentheses.

Answer (score 20):

**BE VERY CAREFUL**, the problem may come from **multibytes encoding** and inappropriate PHP functions used...

It was the case for me and it took me a while to figure it out.

For example, I get the a **string from MySQL using utf8mb4** (very common now to encode emojis):

```
$formattedString = strtolower($stringFromMysql);
$strCleaned = iconv('UTF-8', 'utf-8//TRANSLIT', $formattedString); // WILL RETURN THE ERROR 'Detected an illegal character in input string'
```

> The problem does not stand in `iconv()` but stands in `strtolower()`
>   in this case.

The appropriate way is to use **Multibyte String Functions** **`mb_strtolower()`** instead of **`strtolower()`**

```
$formattedString = mb_strtolower($stringFromMysql);
$strCleaned = iconv('UTF-8', 'utf-8//TRANSLIT', $formattedString); // WORK FINE
```

---

### MORE INFO

More examples of this issue are available at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138120/5519544)

PHP Manual on the [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

Answer (score 17):

### PHP 7.2

```php
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// "e@uu$`a"

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// "@$`"

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// "e@uu$`a"
```

### PHP 7.4

```php
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// "@$`"

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'é@ùµ$`à');
// "e@u$`a"

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC')->transliterate('é@ùµ$`à'))
// "e@uu$`a" -> same as PHP 7.2
```

Comment: ^^^this (ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE) is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found one Solution :

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode($string));
```

use utf8_encode()

Comment: `utf8_encode` is obsolete in PHP 8.2.
https://www.php.net/manual/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

this bellow solution worked for me

```
$result_encr="##Sƒ";

iconv("cp1252", "utf-8//IGNORE", $result_encr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with files with "é" characters in ASCII format generated by Notepad++

```
$row_tmp[$index]=iconv("ASCII", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$value);
```

Using

```
$row_tmp[$index]=iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$value);
```

...seems to solve it (using a Windows computer with Belgian locale).
iconv apparently needs the exact code of the ASCII extension for the source encoding.
**mb_detect_encoding** returns "**ASCII**" for the same file, so be careful if the source encoding parameter comes from a variable...