# iconv_strlen() - //IGNORE not work

Tags: php, encoding, iconv, strlen, libiconv

In one script i founded a error from iconv_strlen() function. It try check utf8-len of string in cp1251.

```
$len = iconv_strlen($cp1252str, "utf-8");
```

I try use "utf-8//IGNORE" for mute error, but it do not work. Here is example with iconv (//IGNORE work) and iconv_strlen (//IGNORE not work)

```
<?php
$cp1252str = '';

for ($i = 128; $i < 256; $i++) {
    $cp1252str .= chr($i);
}

iconv("cp1252", "utf-8//IGNORE", $cp1252str);
iconv_strlen($cp1252str, "utf-8//IGNORE");
```

Output:

> PHP Notice:  iconv_strlen(): Detected an illegal character in input
>   string in /home/user/tmp/test.php on line 9 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1.
>   {main}() /home/user/tmp/test.php:0 PHP   2. iconv_strlen()
>   /home/user/tmp/test.php:9

How can i mute this error? Only with @?

Comment: See that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727735/iconv-detected-an-illegal-character-in-input-string

Comment: What can i see there? Only solutions for iconv(), but i have problem with iconv_strlen().

Answer (score 0):

Get answer on
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71346&edit=2

> That's because the charset parameter in iconv_strlen() is for the
>   input string, while the "//IGNORE" flag is only intended to be used in
>   the output charset during conversion, in the iconv() call.
>
> "//IGNORE" means the characters that cannot be represented in the
>   output charset will be discarded. But in your case, you are giving an
>   input string that is invalid UTF-8, and telling iconv_strlen() that it
>   is encoded in the UTF-8 charset, so you are correctly receiving a
>   notice that your input string contains an illegal character.