# php substr() function with utf-8 leaves � marks at the end

Tags: php, utf-8, substr

Here is simple code

```
<?php

$var = "Бензин Офиси А.С. также производит все типы жира и смазок и их побочных        продуктов в его смесительных установках нефти машинного масла в Деринце, Измите, Алиага и Измире. У Компании есть 3 885 станций технического обслуживания, включая сжиженный газ (ЛПГ) станции под фирменным знаком Петрогаз, приблизительно 5 000 дилеров, двух смазочных смесительных установок, 12 терминалов, и 26 единиц поставки аэропорта.";

$foo = substr($var,0,142);

echo $foo;
?>
```

and it outputs something like this:

Бензин Офиси А.С. также производит все типы жира и смазок и их побочных продук�...

I tried mb_substr() with no luck. How to do this the right way?

Comment: `mb_substr()` is way to go, this happens when a multi-byte character gets cut in half. Can you show what you tried with that and how it failed?

Comment: Did you specify the encoding (last parameter) when you tried `mb_substr`?

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried to do. I don't have it up on internet so I can't provide link. Its a long description of the company, which I cut to be 142 characters long to display on the home page of one website.

Comment: @JohnFlatness No, I didn't scpecify, I just replaced substr() with mb_substr(). Let me check

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I didn't specify the last argument of mb_substr() function which is "UTF-8" as @JohnFlatness noted. Now everything works great! Thak you very much guys!

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The comments above are correct so long as you have mbstring enabled on your server.

```
$var = "Бензин Офиси А.С. также производит все типы жира и смазок и их побочных        продуктов в его смесительных установках нефти машинного масла в Деринце, Измите, Алиага и Измире. У Компании есть 3 885 станций технического обслуживания, включая сжиженный газ (ЛПГ) станции под фирменным знаком Петрогаз, приблизительно 5 000 дилеров, двух смазочных смесительных установок, 12 терминалов, и 26 единиц поставки аэропорта.";

$foo = mb_substr($var,0,142, "utf-8");
```

Here's the php docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: Thank you! The last argument that I missed was "UTF-8", tho I looked through documentation.

Answer (score 6):

A proper (logical) alternative for unicode strings;

```
<?php
function substr_unicode($str, $s, $l = null) {
    return join("", array_slice(
        preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), $s, $l));
}

$str = "Büyük";
$s = 0; // start from "0" (nth) char
$l = 3; // get "3" chars
echo substr($str, $s, $l) ."\n";    // Bü
echo mb_substr($str, $s, $l) ."\n"; // Bü
echo substr_unicode($str, $s, $l);  // Büy
?>
```

Use the [PHP: mb_substr - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: `mb_substr($str, $s, $l, 'UTF-8')` is the real proper alternative…! Without a correctly specified character set it's a crapshoot what the result is.

Comment: In PHP 5.6 that's the only working alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If your strings may contain Unicode (multi-byte) characters and you don’t want to break these, replace `substr` with one of the following two, depending on what you want:

Limit to **142 characters**:

```
mb_substr($var, 0, 142);
```

Limit to **142 bytes**:

```
mb_strcut($var, 0, 142);
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP5 does not understand UTF-8 natively. It is proposed for PHP6, if it ever comes out.

Use the [multibyte string functions](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to manipulate UTF-8 strings safely.

For instance, `mb_substr()` in your case.

Comment: It turns out they skipped PHP 6 and went straight to PHP 7. There is still no native unicode support. Perl has had it since at least Perl 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

Never use constant in `substr` function for `UTF-8` string:

```
$st = substr($text, $beg, 100);
```

50% chance you will get half of a character at end of the string.

Do it like this:

```
$postion_degin = strpos($text, $first_symbol);
$postion_end = strpos($text, $last_symbol);
$len = $postion_end - $postion_degin + 1;
$st = substr($text, $postion_degin, $len);
```

100% safe result.

No `mb_substr`.

Comment: Cool if you know which chars you want to cut. If you want to have only, let's say the first 3 chars of a random string, it's no good. The correct way is with mb_substr.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `strlen` function, to calculate length of string, which you want to return and your string `$word` has `UTF-8` encoding, you have to use `mb_strlen()` function:

`$foo = mb_substr($word, 0, mb_strlen($word)-1);`

Comment: That works ```mb_substr``` perfectly. I tried ```substr``` not working :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution help you as it helped me a lot.

```
<?php
if(mb_strlen($post->post_content,'UTF-8')>200){
    $content= str_replace('\n', '', mb_substr(strip_tags($post-> post_content), 
                          0, 200,'UTF-8'));
    echo $content.'…';
}else{
    echo str_replace('\n', '', strip_tags($post->post_content));
}
?>
```