# Limiting the output of PHP to 100 characters

Tags: php, html

Am trying to limit the output of this code 
`<tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px; height:10px\">".$postDetails['big_title']."</td></tr>`

So it will be from this "blah blah blah blah" to 100 characthers "blah blah.." in UTF8?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to keep at most 100 characters of your string.
Example:

```
<tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px; height:10px\">".substr($postDetails['big_title'], 0, 100)."</td></tr>
```

Comment: you have to use php tag to use substr

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087502/php-substr-function-with-utf-8-leaves-%EF%BF%BD-marks-at-the-end for utf-8 problem handling.

Comment: @GHugo So it will be? An example like last one before plz

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
substr(strip_tags($postDetails['big_title']), 0, 70);
```

It will strip out any additional elements within the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the string exceeds 100 chars, if yes, the use `substr` and append the ellipsis, if not just leave it as it is. Example:

```
$big_title = (strlen($postDetails['big_title']) > 100) ? substr($postDetails['big_title'], 0, 100) . '&hellip;' : $postDetails['big_title'];

echo "
    <tr>
        <td 
            valign=\"middle\" 
            style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px; height:10px\"
        >"
        .$big_title.
        "</td>
    </tr>";
```

Comment: @vlzvl wow i did not know there is such thing, nice suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The asker states that he wanted ellipses. I think a custom function would work very nice for this:

```
function limitOutput($string, $limit){
    if (strlen($string) > $limit){
        $string = substr($string, 0, $limit - 3) . '...';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
<tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px;height:10px\">".limitOutput($postDetails['big_title'],100)."</td></tr>
```

**EDIT** - Response to it not working:

```
<?php

function limitOutput($string, $limit){
    if (strlen($string) > $limit){
        $string = substr($string, 0, $limit - 3) . '...';
    }
    return $string;
}

$postDetails['big_title'] = str_repeat('12345678901234567890', 20);

echo $postDetails['big_title'].'<br><br>';

echo "<tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px;height:10px\">".limitOutput($postDetails['big_title'],100)."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: @user3590788 I tested it with the code above in my edited answer and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

`<tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size:12px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:5px; height:10px\">".substr($postDetails['big_title'], 0, 100)."</td></tr>`   add this  , 0, 100, 'utf-8') ." …