# PHP substr() function is not working as expected

Tags: php, string

I am removing the first character of the string and I am using substr(); function for that. 
For example :

```
<?php
$amount =  '€300';
echo substr($amount ,1);
?>
```

This code is doing its work fine but it have some bug. When I display the substr() function applied string then it display something other symbol at the beginning of the string. Below image has output.[image]

In above image you can see its displaying unwanted symbol. But when I apply substr() function again it works successfull. 
I just want to know why this function having that symbol? what does this symbol mean? Why its coming in the output?

Comment: Seems to work fine in PHPFiddle too.

Comment: This probably is an issue with your php setup, your configuration. This looks as if you are trying to apply the 8 bit function to a utf encoded string which certainly will not work.Please read about unicode support in php and about the `mbstring` extension and "function overloading"`.

Comment: The problem seem to happen with the `€` symbol but not with `$`

Comment: This happens when you strip a byte of a multibyte character. You should use multibyte-aware string functions (`mb_*`) for multibyte-encoded strings (e. g. UTF-8). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087502/php-substr-function-with-utf-8-leaves-marks-at-the-end?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using `utf8_decode`, i.e.:

```
$amount =  utf8_decode('€300');
echo substr($amount ,1);
//300
```

Answer (score 2):

you could using `mb_substr()` php function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

```
<?php
$amount =  '€300';
echo mb_substr($amount, 1, NULL, "UTF-8");
?>
```