# Invalid utf8 character string. Converting "latin1_german1_ci" column entirely into UTF8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, iso-8859-1, character-set

I have a table with a column that has data that seems not to be UTF8. I want to convert that column into UTF8.

I found this wonderful tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/gjyuwg/mysql-convert-encoding-to-utf8-without-garbled-data

However, none of these solutions really work.

When I do

```
UPDATE vbpmtext 
SET message = @txt 
WHERE char_length(message) =  LENGTH(@txt := CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(message USING latin1) USING utf8));
```

I get a ton of errors like this:

```
Invalid utf8 character string: 'FC6265'
```

with different "strings" (FC6265 is just an example).

Is there any way I can rescue this data?

The column we are speaking of is naturally formatted with a collation of `latin1_german1_ci`.

Comment: Sorry.  I can't seem to log into that coderwall link, or I would give them a piece of my mind.  The problem is not as simple as they make it out to be.  Furthermore, the provide multiple solutions without saying which applies when!

Answer (score 2):

Interpreted as latin1, `FC6265` is `übe`.  (Ditto for cp1250, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, latin2, latin5, latin7.)

Was `@txt` the 3-character string `übe`?  Or the 6-character string `FC6265`?

```
mysql> SET @in := UNHEX('FC6265');
mysql> SELECT HEX(@in);
+----------+
| HEX(@in) |
+----------+
| FC6265   |
+----------+
mysql> SELECT HEX( CONVERT(@in USING latin1) );
+----------------------------------+
| HEX( CONVERT(@in USING latin1) ) |
+----------------------------------+
| FC6265                           |
+----------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT HEX( BINARY(CONVERT(@in USING latin1)) );
+------------------------------------------+
| HEX( BINARY(CONVERT(@in USING latin1)) ) |
+------------------------------------------+
| FC6265                                   |
+------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT HEX( CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(@in USING latin1) USING utf8) );
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX( CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(@in USING latin1) USING utf8) ) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1300 | Invalid utf8 character string: 'FC6265' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Using `BINARY()` takes away any assumption of what the string is currently encoded as.  So it takes the simplest approach and assumes the string is already `utf8`.

This is probably the shortest way:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(@in USING latin1) USING utf8);
+-----------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(CONVERT(@in USING latin1) USING utf8) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| übe                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**But...** what is the charset of the column?  If it is latin1, you are making a worse mess.  Do *not* do any changes without first testing further.   [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) are several cases and the fix for each.  Do *not* rush into one solution before figuring out if you have that case; you are likely to make things worse.  See also [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

**Example**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE ube ( c VARCHAR(8) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci );

mysql> INSERT INTO ube (c) VALUES (UNHEX('FC6265'));

mysql> SELECT HEX(c) FROM ube;
+--------+
| HEX(c) |
+--------+
| FC6265 |  -- Note the latin1 encoding
+--------+

mysql> ALTER TABLE ube CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0   -- Note: no errors

mysql> SELECT HEX(c) FROM ube;
+----------+
| HEX(c)   |
+----------+
| C3BC6265 |   -- Now utf8mb4 encoding
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My table is: `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci`. This does not work: `ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;`.

Comment: The 2-step alter under `Then to convert the column without changing the bytes:` also doesn`t work. In both cases I get this error: `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.`

Comment: @Hillcow - The first ALTER works for me.  See Example in my Answer.  What do you have with `SELECT HEX(col)`?

Comment: You _must_ verify which case you have before performing a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this was my fault. It wasn't that the data itself was corrupted, but I was using php substr method on the data which cut the data at unfortunate places. A solution was found here: [php substr() function with utf-8 leaves � marks at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087502/php-substr-function-with-utf-8-leaves-marks-at-the-end)

```
$var = "Бензин Офиси А.С. также производит все типы жира и смазок и их побочных        продуктов в его смесительных установках нефти машинного масла в Деринце, Измите, Алиага и Измире. У Компании есть 3 885 станций технического обслуживания, включая сжиженный газ (ЛПГ) станции под фирменным знаком Петрогаз, приблизительно 5 000 дилеров, двух смазочных смесительных установок, 12 терминалов, и 26 единиц поставки аэропорта.";

$foo = mb_substr($var,0,142, "utf-8");
```