# not supported character in php

Tags: php

I'm having a problem in inserting data in php. It sometimes create a character like a black diamond with a question mark.
[image]

do you have any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are not encoding the characters properly. Check that your database/table collation is `UTF-8` to begin with.

Comment: What is current character encoding? Did you performed any manipulations with text (split, substr, regex, etc.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the same encoding everywhere and define it.

Define the charset like this;

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

and in the header;

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You can also  write your characters with [html characters](http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm), however it is always good to define the charset.

---

If you have `ISO-8859-1`(`latin1`) data in your database, and the rest of the site in `UTF-8`. Then define the charset-tag as above and use the function [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to give the string a properly encoding. There is also a reverse function called [utf8_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)