# Special characters are lost (replaced by '?') in AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

I've got a little issue with AJAX request. I request some data from database using jQuery $.post, but all the special characters are lost. I did some testing and I've figured out, that it stores the data incorrectly in `$_SESSION`, but it only occurs with AJAX request when the file contains only PHP (in html files I have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` markup and it seems to work for PHP too). Of course I've tried adding `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');` to the code, but it doesn't work. What could it be?

Comment: In which encoding are the PHP files saved? Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark).

Comment: The PHP files are saved in the same encoding as html files which have no issues with special characters.

Comment: It shouldn't affect PHP behaviour, but make sure that `default_charset = "UTF-8"` is turned on in php.ini.

Comment: any updates on this ?