# PHP shows nothing, no error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I am trying to fetch data from **users** table but PHP shows blank page and no error. Where am I wrong? I am newbie in PHP.

```
<?php


$host ="localhost";
$database="xyz"; //I am sure that here is true
$username="xyz"; //I am sure that here is true
$password="xyz"; //I am sure that here is true

$sql = "select * from users;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  array_push($response,array("name" => $row[0],"email" => $row[1],"contact" => $row[2],"password" => $row[3]));

}

echo json_encode(array("server_response" =>$response));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**EDİT**

I added `var_dump($row);` in **while** loop

```
<?php


error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


$host ="localhost";
$database="gurkanc1_sample";
$username="gurkanc1_sample";
$password="Sample123";

$sql = "select * from users;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  array_push($response,array("name" => $row[0],"email" => $row[1],"contact" => $row[2],"password" => $row[3]));
  var_dump($row);


}


echo json_encode(array("server_response" =>$response));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Now it shows,

```
> array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "asd" ["name"]=> string(3) "asd" [1]=>
> string(3) "asd" ["email"]=> string(3) "asd" [2]=> string(2) "aa"
> ["contact"]=> string(2) "aa" [3]=> string(2) "aa" ["password"]=>
> string(2) "aa" } array(8) { [0]=> string(13) "Merhaba D�nya"
> ["name"]=> string(13) "Merhaba D�nya" [1]=> string(7) "Merhaba"
> ["email"]=> string(7) "Merhaba" [2]=> string(7) "Merhaba"
> ["contact"]=> string(7) "Merhaba" [3]=> string(7) "Merhaba"
> ["password"]=> string(7) "Merhaba" } array(8) { [0]=> string(0) ""
> ["name"]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) ""
> [2]=> string(0) "" ["contact"]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) ""
> ["password"]=> string(0) "" } array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "ss"
> ["name"]=> string(2) "ss" [1]=> string(2) "ss" ["email"]=> string(2)
> "ss" [2]=> string(2) "ss" ["contact"]=> string(2) "ss" [3]=> string(1)
> "s" ["password"]=> string(1) "s" } array(8) { [0]=> string(4) "axac"
> ["name"]=> string(4) "axac" [1]=> string(3) "qdq" ["email"]=>
> string(3) "qdq" [2]=> string(4) "egeg" ["contact"]=> string(4) "egeg"
> [3]=> string(3) "wff" ["password"]=> string(3) "wff" } array(8) {
> [0]=> string(7) "merhaba" ["name"]=> string(7) "merhaba" [1]=>
> string(7) "nerbaba" ["email"]=> string(7) "nerbaba" [2]=> string(3)
> "cii" ["contact"]=> string(3) "cii" [3]=> string(4) "asdf"
> ["password"]=> string(4) "asdf" } array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "g"
> ["name"]=> string(1) "g" [1]=> string(1) "e" ["email"]=> string(1) "e"
> [2]=> string(2) "er" ["contact"]=> string(2) "er" [3]=> string(1) "r"
> ["password"]=> string(1) "r" } array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "sd"
> ["name"]=> string(2) "sd" [1]=> string(2) "sd" ["email"]=> string(2)
> "sd" [2]=> string(3) "dsd" ["contact"]=> string(3) "dsd" [3]=>
> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Turn php error reporting on. error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: What is the contents of `mysqli_error($con)`?

Comment: I can not see ini.php no php.ini file in my hosting.

Comment: I used to get this when a table didn't exist. Are you sure `users` exists?

Comment: Sloan it is not working I added top of the code but nothing changes. 
Gentleman I do not know contents of mysqli_error($con) I am newbie how to kno?

Comment: Yes users table is existing.

Comment: There might not be any syntax errors, not mysqli errors. If you do `echo 'hello';` do you get `hello`?

Comment: @chris85 yes I get echo. I can see echo value but this code is not working.

Comment: What is `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: @chris85 how to learn? I am newbie

Comment: @chris85 I added this code at the end. 
I get this when I refresh the page. 
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(8) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Edit your question and put that at the end instead of in a comment. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: What's `var_dump($row);` in the `while` give you?

Comment: What is `echo $result -> num_rows`?

Comment: @chris85 I edited question can you look what should I do ?

Comment: One suggestion in the line that starts with _array_push($response,array("name" => $row[0],_, use the column names instead of indexes. If the table definition changes the indexes will also change. IOW instead of $row[0], use $row['name'].

Comment: Okay, so your fields are populated. After `while` with is `$response`? `var_dump($response);`.

Comment: `json_encode` needs utf-8 only data, get sure about it.

Comment: The `�` seems like your `mysqli` connection isnt UTF8.

Comment: Thankssss @Deadooshka I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the json looks when formatted with Json viewer plugin, it appears to be wrongly formed

```
>array(8){
    [0]=>string(3)"asd"["name"]=>string(3)"asd"[1]=>>string(3)"asd"["email"]=>string(3)"asd"[2]=>string(2)"aa">["contact"]=>string(2)"aa"[3]=>string(2)"aa"["password"]=>>string(2)"aa"
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(13)"Merhaba D�nya">["name"]=>string(13)"Merhaba D�nya"[1]=>string(7)"Merhaba">["email"]=>string(7)"Merhaba"[2]=>string(7)"Merhaba">["contact"]=>string(7)"Merhaba"[3]=>string(7)"Merhaba">["password"]=>string(7)"Merhaba"
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(0)"">["name"]=>string(0)""[1]=>string(0)""["email"]=>string(0)"">[2]=>string(0)""["contact"]=>string(0)""[3]=>string(0)"">["password"]=>string(0)""
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(2)"ss">["name"]=>string(2)"ss"[1]=>string(2)"ss"["email"]=>string(2)>"ss"[2]=>string(2)"ss"["contact"]=>string(2)"ss"[3]=>string(1)>"s"["password"]=>string(1)"s"
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(4)"axac">["name"]=>string(4)"axac"[1]=>string(3)"qdq"["email"]=>>string(3)"qdq"[2]=>string(4)"egeg"["contact"]=>string(4)"egeg">[3]=>string(3)"wff"["password"]=>string(3)"wff"
}array(8){
    >[0]=>string(7)"merhaba"["name"]=>string(7)"merhaba"[1]=>>string(7)"nerbaba"["email"]=>string(7)"nerbaba"[2]=>string(3)>"cii"["contact"]=>string(3)"cii"[3]=>string(4)"asdf">["password"]=>string(4)"asdf"
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(1)"g">["name"]=>string(1)"g"[1]=>string(1)"e"["email"]=>string(1)"e">[2]=>string(2)"er"["contact"]=>string(2)"er"[3]=>string(1)"r">["password"]=>string(1)"r"
}array(8){
    [0]=>string(2)"sd">["name"]=>string(2)"sd"[1]=>string(2)"sd"["email"]=>string(2)>"sd"[2]=>string(3)"dsd"["contact"]=>string(3)"dsd"[3]=>>string(0)""["password"]=>string(0)""
}
```

Can you please post the var_dump($result) or print_r($result). It could be as others have suggested the table itself might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to encoding.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275448/3578036) solved it for me.

In short: make sure encoding is correct.

Adding this at the top of your page should help.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem it was about Turkish characters. There was some turkish characters like **ü** in my database. Then truncated my table and added again some english characters in my database. Now my problem is solved.

Comment: I wouldn't consider truncating your table an answer. Why don't you make the DB connection utf8

Answer (score -3):

Add this at start of script (as code, not in php.ini):

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Then if you still don't get anything, check mysql table with phpmyadmin. Could be empty.

Try adding this after $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

```
echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con). "\n";
```