# remove question mark on mcrypt_ecb() php function

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt-ecb

I use this code for encrypt and decrypt string.
but this code create question mark

```
$key="123456789098776545433322";
$test=mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $key, 'test', MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
$result=mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $test, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);  
<input type="text"     value="<?=$result?>"   name="test">
```

result is

> test����

Comment: First of all, `mcrypt_ecb` is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-ecb.php. I suggest you to check for alternative rather than this.

Comment: @hassan  this is my header <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

Comment: For Alternative, check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/php-7-mcrypt-deprecated-need-alternative

Comment: @hassan It isn't about encoding. Those are NULL bytes.

Comment: You can also check this out - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php

Comment: just do this once `$result = trim($result);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark/15138120

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: **Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: **Don't use mcrypt nowadays**, because it is abandonware containing many bugs.