# php mysqli populated select has diamond question marks in it?

Tags: php, mysql, select, populate

I have populated a select with information from a mysql database.
However all characters with accents on them (i.e ç, á, õ, etc.) appear as question-marks within a diamond (see image below).

[Diamond question marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg3XX.png)

The code is sound it's just these diamonds, how do I make it so the actual letters appear?

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled>District...</option>
    <?php
        $sql="SELECT dist_name FROM districts;";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo'   <option value="'.$row['dist_num'].'">'.$row['dist_name'].'</option> ';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Thank you for your help in advance! :D

PS: The language is Portuguese

Comment: This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/275448/5509627

Comment: @Tristan Thank you very much, I was lacking a header... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an HTML page correctly, a web browser must know which character set (character encoding) to use.

This is specified in the  tag:

For HTML4:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">`

For HTML5:
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
to the php

Comment: Instead of adding it in php file. you should be add it in HTML page. to avoid inconsistences in code.

Comment: Yes, no problem!