# Translate the names of the days in other languages

Tags: php

Hello to everyone i'm new to PHP... with this function i have the name of the days between two dates, but i can't translate it in italian without broken it. Can someone help me?
I tried to use strftime() in this two modes, but it gives me the error: strftime() expects parameter 2 to be int, object given, i have done the var_dump of date and it is object, I need to cast it or it is not the answer to my question?

```
$from_date = new DateTime($from_date);
    $to_date = new DateTime($to_date);

    for ($date = $from_date; $date <= $to_date; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
       echo $date->format('l') . "\n";
       //echo strftime("%A", $date); error : strftime() expects parameter 2 to be int, object given
      //var_dump($date);  object(DateTime)
      }
```

output: Wednesday Thursday Friday

I pick $from_date and $to_date from :

```
+------------+------------+
| from_date  | to_date    |
+============+============+
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-03 |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How are $from_date and $to_date defined ?

Comment: @T.Zen is better now?

Comment: And if you put setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8'); before $from_date and $to_date ?

Comment: the same result as the one I updated above the names with �...

Comment: @axel I think you need to set the header `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using:

```
for ($date = $from_date; $date <= $to_date; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
      echo utf8_encode (strftime("%A", $date->getTimestamp())).PHP_EOL;  
     }
```

> output: mercoledì giovedì venerdì

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you if you set the locale properly `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8');`. I've also modified your code a little bit to make it more readable and concise.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8');
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('2020-04-07'),new DateInterval('P1D'),new DateTime('2020-04-18'));
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
  echo strftime("%A", $value->getTimestamp()).PHP_EOL;     
}
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/sYirG

Comment: I use your format with my variable and new output is: Wednesday Thursday, i have not idea why doesn't works... My code is this :
`<?php $from_date = new DateTime($from_date);
    $to_date = new DateTime($to_date);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8');
    $period = new DatePeriod($from_date,new DateInterval('P1D'),$to_date);
    foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
      echo strftime("%A", $value->getTimestamp()).PHP_EOL;} ?>`
It's really strange because in your example works

Comment: Maybe the problem is xampp?

Comment: @axel You man need to set the header `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");` also have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138120/1138192

Comment: SET_LOCALE documentation: Warning
The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS, HHVM or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale().